# Problems loading module when separating files into directories

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on an AngularJS 1 and Rails 4.2 application. I'm using AngularRailsTemplates to load my AngularJS templates.

I currently have all of the AngularJS controllers, config, routing, and factories in [one single file](https://github.com/kylesb/diction.help/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js). I'm trying to separate these entities into designated directories (i.e. see below).

```
| application.js

    | controllers
        | guest.js
        | user.js

    | factories
        | lists.js

    | templates
        | home.html
        | dashboard.html
```

I have separated the controller and factory files into modules. So for example, in my controller directory, I have two controller files:

controllers/guest.js

```
angular.module('diction.controllers')

/*  Guest Controller 
 *  controller for static clientside for guest users
 *
*/
.controller('GuestCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Auth', '$http', '$window',
    // logic
}]);
```

controllers/user.js

```
angular.module('diction.controllers')

/*  User Controller 
 *  controller for users
 *
*/
.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Auth', '$http', '$window',
    // logic
}]);
```

I'm trying to load these controller modules in my application.js file, it currently looks like this.

```
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree .

angular.module('diction', [
    'ui.router', 
    'templates', 
    'diction.controllers'
])

/*  Routing configuration for various 'states'
 *
*/
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',

    // Set state providers
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {$stateProvider

        // home
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'home.html',
          controller: 'GuestCtrl',
        })

    }
]);
```

When I view the page, I'm getting a "Module Unavailable" error:

> Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable
>
> Module 'diction.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled
>   the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure
>   that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Any helpful tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about your index.html? are you including the js files with the dependencies? like so...   
 <script src="controllers/guest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine, that you used `diction.controllers` as reference from angular, and did not create it.

Try the `diction.controllers` init part with

```
angular.module('diction.controllers', []);
```

So it results into

```
angular.module('diction.controllers', [])
.controller('GuestCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Auth', '$http', '$window',
    // logic
}]);
```

Comment: So I need to have the init (dependencies) part in each controller file?

Comment: No, but you have to init a module (with dependencies) once and before refering it (without dependencies)